# How can I copy the list<E> into the current array list in java? ( Generic list)

Tags: java, list, generics

```
  public class ArrayList<E> {
       public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;

       private int size; // number of occupied space
       private E[] data; // ArrayList, encapsulate with the private keyword

       public ArrayList() {
          this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
          size = 0;
       }

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       public ArrayList(int capacity) {
           data = (E[])new Object[capacity];
           size = 0;

           if(capacity < 0) {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Capacity should more than 0");
           }
       }

       //Need to be fixed
       //
       //
       //
       public ArrayList(List<E> other) {
           List<E> newList = new ArrayList<E>();


       }
}
```

This is my code, and I made a constructor with the parameter( List other), the last one.
    I try to copy the list into the current array list; the E[] data, variable.
    But the error is List cannot copy the data to the E[]. 
    So, I'm a little bit confused. How can I copy them? if I cannot How can I copy the List ?

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to create the ArrayList, when the functionality already exist in Java.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public ArrayList(List<E> other) {
       data = (E[]) other.toArray();
       size = data.length;
   }
```

We are making use of the `toArray()` method implemented by all `List` types.

Alternatively allocate an array and copy the elements with a loop of the appropriate kind.  (Avoid using `get(i)` because it is `O(N)` for some kinds of list.)

Notes:

1. It is a bad idea to give your class the same name as a commonly used class in the standard library (`java.util.ArrayList`)
2. Your class doesn't implement `java.util.List<E>`.  Should it?
3. If you are implementing `java.util.List<E>` you could save a lot of implementation effort by extending `java.util.AbstractList<E>`.